# Knockout causing dysfunctional accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I got this jquery accordion code:

```
 $(function () {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $("#accordion")
      .accordion({
          header: "> div > h3",
          collapsible: true,
          active: false,
          heightStyle: "content",
          icons: icons
      })
      .sortable({
          axis: "y",
          handle: "h3",
          stop: function (event, ui) {
              var items = [];
              ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                  //compare data('index') and the real index
                  if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                      items.push(this.id);
                  }
              });
              // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
              // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
              ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
              ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
          }
      })
    .on('stop', function () {
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
            //kjører for alle "childs" i accordian...
            $(this).data('index', i);
        });
    })
    .trigger('stop');
});
```

This works fine with a static HTML like the following:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div id ="Scene 1" class="group">
        <h3><b>#1: Task no 1</b></h3>
        <div>
             <textarea > Description of first task </textarea>
        </div>
    <div id ="Scene 2" class="group">
        <h3><b>#2: Task no 2/b></h3>
        <div>
            <textarea> Decription of task</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But after making the HTML dynamic with knockout, the accordion no longer expands (or collapses) when clicking on the title.

Here´s the knockout/dynamic HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: Tasks">
    <div data-bind="attr : {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}" class="group">
        <h3><b>#<span data-bind="text: TaskId"></span>: <span data-bind="text: Taskname"></span></b></h3>
        <div>
             <textarea data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any errors in the browser dev console? So in Chrome, you need to press F12 (I think) or if you're like me and use Firefox, install FireBug then press F12 on the web page.

- Chrome Dev
  Console: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console
- FireBug: https://getfirebug.com/

These tools will definitely help you debug Javascript errors. I can't see much wrong with your syntax.

Comment: Excellent idea. I get this: "TypeError: a is undefined"...

Maybe it´s down to DNN (I´m running in a Dotnetnuke framework)?

Another strange thing that happens is my accordion icons appear with a line break after... Obviously due to DNN as it works fine in fiddler...

Comment: I do not have any experience with DNN so I cannot comment whether that is the problem. If you want to rule out data-bind issues, take out the contents of #accordion and replace it with scene2 div from your static html example (scene1 div is missing an ending div). I'm also wondering if `Taskname` should be `TaskName` going by your naming convention?

Comment: Thanks again user985351! :)

The error is due to the for each data-bind. 
data-bind="foreach: Tasks"

removing this cause the expand/collapse to work.

However it doesn´t fix my problem...

Comment: @AsleG - How do you set up the data for the bindings? Some code for that would be helpful.

Comment: The bindings actually works. It lists out my items.
Here is how I do it:

Comment: The bindings actually works. It lists out my items.
Here is how I do it:  
    Task = function(model){ 
        self.TaskId = model.TaskId;
        self.TaskName = ko.observable(model.SceneTitle);
    };

then in my viewModel:
...
    self.Tasks = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON(
        myUrl,
        function (allData) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                return new Task(item)
            });
           
            self.Tasks(mappedTasks);
    });

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle example I quickly made: http://jsfiddle.net/k5gfA/ - it should be noted that initialising the accordion only worked after doing the knockout stuff first.

Comment: hanks a lot! It proves it can be down. I even updated your fiddle with some additional complexity http://jsfiddle.net/k5gfA/3/
This is now so to say exactly the same code I have that doesn´t work.

At least it can be done! :)


Just wondering where the bug is...

Comment: I have upgraded DNN to the latest release. Now running jquery 1.9.1 and query-ui-1-10-3. Still it does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this from the knockout forum, so no credits to me but to zew...:

He writes: "
if it's related to rendering then a simple test with setTimeout should help ... I've edited your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/k5gfA/5/"

Basically zew just put the timeoutfunction around the accordion function like this:

```
 $(function () {

 setTimeout( function() {
    $("#accordion")
      .accordion({
          header: "> div > h3"
          ,collapsible: true
          ,active: false
          ,heightStyle: "content"
      })
      .sortable({
          axis: "y",
          handle: "h3",
          stop: function (event, ui) {
              var items = [];
              ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                  //compare data('index') and the real index
                  if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                      items.push(this.id);
                  }
              });
              // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
              // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
              ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
              // Now, print out the order of the accordion...
              if (items.length) $("#sekvens").text(items.join(','));
              ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
          }
      })
      .on('stop', function () {
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
            $(this).data('index', i);
        });
     })
     .trigger('stop');
 }, 1000);
});
```

The setTimeout actually solves the issue. 
Must be due to DNN delaying the rendering somehow (??)
Anyhow the code as it is in the jsfiddle fix the problem in DNN.
(NOTE: I have upgrader DNN to version 7.1.1. which run jQuery-1.9.1 and jQuery-UI-1.10.3)

Thanks for all the help everyone!!!! :D

Comment: I was too quick. The setTimeout()- makes my data render the first time  (after page load). My Tasks() are updated through a ko.subscription. If values are updated the accordion expands all data and stop working again....

Comment: When you say 'stop working', do you mean the values don't update? If so, your properties in Task have to be observable e.g. `TaskId = ko.observable()`

Comment: The values do update, but the the accordion is no more sortable and the first item is expanded and will only be collapsed if I choose another item. At the end theres a dummy row, just showing an arrow and a line.